# What does it mean by "bondsman's two hundred and fifty years of..." in Lincoln's 2nd inaugural adress?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, literary-english

I'm not sure who is the bondsman and why his wealth matters here.

Here is the quote, from the paragraph of [Lincoln's Second Inaugural Address](http://www.bartleby.com/124/pres32.html)

> Yet, if God wills that it continue until all the wealth piled by the
>   bondsman's two hundred and fifty years of unrequited toil shall be
>   sunk, and until every drop of blood drawn with the lash shall be paid
>   by another drawn with the sword, as was said three thousand years ago,
>   so still it must be said "the judgments of the Lord are true and
>   righteous altogether.

Comment: 'If the only way we're going to be rid of the heritage of slavery ...'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He is referring to slavery; bondsman - a male slave

President Lincoln’s [Second inaugural Address](http://www.gilderlehrman.org/history-by-era/american-civil-war/resources/president-lincoln%E2%80%99s-second-inaugural-address-1865) , 1865:

> - Just 701 words long, Lincoln’s Second Inaugural Address took only six or seven minutes to deliver, yet contains many of the most memorable phrases in American political oratory. The speech contained neither gloating nor rejoicing. Rather, it offered Lincoln’s most profound reflections on the causes and meaning of the war. The “scourge of war,” he explained, was best understood as divine punishment for the sin of slavery, a sin in which all Americans, North as well as South, were complicit. It describes a national moral debt that had been created by the **“bondsmen’s 250 years of unrequited toil,”** and ends with a call for compassion and reconciliation.

(from www.gilderlehrman.org)

Comment: The 'two hundred and fifty years" confused me here, as USA was only established less than 90 years at that moment. Was he using a metaphor here?

Comment: Colonists began to see indentured servants as too costly, and in 1619, Dutch traders brought the first African slaves to Jamestown, who nonetheless were in North America at first generally treated as indentured servants.http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slavery_in_the_colonial_United_States

Comment: I'm pretty sure Lincoln was not excluding female slaves from this paragraph despite his non-use of **"bondsperson"**.

Comment: "Bondsperson" would not have made any sense to the audience.

Answer (score 1):

"all the wealth piled by the bondsman's two hundred and fifty years of unrequited toil" refers to the material gains extracted from the labors of the African slaves brought to North America continuously from 1619 to 1864. A "bondsman" in the common parlance of the day was a slave, and Lincoln was well aware that slaves had been instrumental in the building of America from the very start. He also knew that money and loot might not be enough to atone for our sins, hence the further warning that the war might need to continue until "every drop of blood drawn with the lash shall be paid by another drawn with the sword". Explaining it thusly leaves nobody off the hook - slavery is the sin of us all, not simply the South. So be it.

Answer (score -2):

In English, the word "man" means both an adult male human being and all human beings regardless of age or sex. The distinction being purely contextual.

The word bondman meaning a man bound to serve without wages, i.e. a slave, came into English in the 12th Century. It appears in the King James Version of the Bible (in the UK, the Authorized Version) in six places as synonym for slave. The term is not contextually gendered.

Lincoln used it in that sense in his Second Inaugural Address. The address has been transcribed several times. You may inspect images of the autograph on the Library of Congress web site. To me, it appears that Lincoln wrote bond_man, and that the underscore  was most likely an attempt to correct an accidental break in the cursive lettering.

The Collected Works of Abraham Lincoln, available online, transcribes the word "bond-man" with a dash rather than an underscore. While the Yale Avalon Project transcribes it as "bondsman", the usage above.

I think that Lincoln's intent was to use the word from KJV, "bondman", and that Avalon is wrong, and Collected works should have noted the variation.

The word bondsman is an English word found in standard dictionaries. It means a surety or a man who has given a deposit of valuable collateral to guarantee the performance of an obligation, most often the obligation of a man accused of a crime to appear in court. It originated in the 18th Century. It is clearly not the word Lincoln intended to use in discussing the American Civil War and its connection to the institution of slavery of African descended human beings.

Lincoln would not have used the word "bondsperson". It is a neologism invented within the last 30 years.

In the 1970s, radical feminists declared that the use of the word man and men to refer to all human beings was an insult to women, and that it should henceforth cease. Many academics and many lawyers obeyed this diktat. The word person which was used in the law to refer to both individual humans and to legal fictions, such as corporations, which have legal rights analogous to those of individual humans, was dragooned into use as a substitute for the word man particularly in compounds, e.g. chairperson for chairman.

Bondsperson, has in some statutes replaced bondsman. Both refer to sureties, not to slaves.

Comment: Yet the *Oxford English Dictionary* lists *bondsman* as a slave or servant, with uses from 1713. Some links to the sources you cite would greatly improve this answer. But it's thought-provoking at least, although I'm not convinced.

Comment: Your question is really one of textual criticism. I'm not sure if arguing what the actual word that was used in versions of the printed text   is on-topic here. Also, unless someone recorded Lincoln's address, which I don't think happened, we can't be sure what he actually *said*.

Comment: Reading "bondsman" as the owner of the sunk (lost) wealth, versus the "bondman" as the toiler who created the wealth does matter to understanding this sentence and its meaning.  "Wealth piled [up]" and "sunk" [as in a sinking fund] , along with "bondsman" lead me to wonder if Lincoln was referring to debts secured by chattel slavery.  Wealth created by slaves' unpaid toil, wiped out (almost wiped out?) as a consequence of the war makes more sense.

Answer (score -4):

A bondsman is the lienholder or "one who has title." A Lord or Admiral or some such thing is your proto-typical "bondsman" and straight up...he ain't toiling much. In short all that "time"(250 years) of "so called work"(toil from the bondsman) will mean nothing gets done or accomplished. Nothing of "lasting value" will be created. Lincoln was a Railroad Lawyer first and foremost. He knew what "paying the bondsman" in fact meant (the track got laid but no locmotive and rolling stock followed) so this is, was and remains a very obvious and practical thing to say to the American People circa 1865.

Comment: Huh? The dictionary says [bondman](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bondman) *(less commonly bondsman):* Slave, Serf. Yes, there is another definition of *bondsman*, but it makes utterly no sense in this paragraph.

Comment: You simply don't understand the context circa the USA and Great Britain circa 1865. The Railroad had the lien on not just the property on "both sides of the track" but even owned what was beneath and of course above the ground. Think of the famous American lumberjack tale of that era and the problem of "man versus machine." The North had the machines...the South had slaves. "As was written 2000 years ago" is a simple way of explaining reality to any and everyone of that time. "The man may have won but insoding he still died while the machine lived on" problem.

Comment: Seems like a pretty strenuous attempt to avoid the obvious interpretation of the passage.

Comment: @DoctorZhivago I don't see how a series of bondholding investors can be said to have performed **unrequited toil** for 250 years: no one would, voluntarily, buy bonds which did not produce a profit. Since slaves are, by definition, unpaid (or in Lincoln's term "unrequited") and are certainly forced by the administration of physical violence to toil then there seems to be only one reasonable interpretation of this rext.

Comment: Context puts the nail in the coffin of this answer. Lincoln has spent virtually all of the address talking about slavery. To claim that he suddenly switches from that to talking about holders of securities when there is another obviously related understanding defies belief.